# User Management with 2FA

Tags: php, security, authentication, member

Can someone suggest a User Management / Login script with 2FA?

Took a look @ userpie, usercake and so on, but they are missing 2FA. Should be php/mysql.

Does not has to be free, but should be "secure" (as secure as it can be nowadays).

Google Authenticator would be nice, additional yubikey support would be perfect.

Comment: are you working with a framework?

Comment: no framework. had a look @ yii, but i had to rebuild the whole site then... so a standalone solution would be perfect.

Comment: ok, you want a very secure website but you dont want to use a framework. I need 1 hour in Yii to build a secure User Managment.

Comment: framework != secure website

Comment: If you use it properly, it will protect you from many types of attack.

This is so because it is used and tested by many people.

Comment: I think so, but when you've never worked with it... ;)
I dont think that I would use it properly... on long term I know I should switch...